# How to Search a JavaScript Collection for the 1st Occurrence Between Multiple Phrases?

Tags: javascript

How can I search a collection for the first occurrence between multiple phrases?  Given the sample test code below, the first condition will always win but I want to search the collection and end my search once I find the first occurrence (related to position in the mark-up) of the phrases in my search in the while loop.

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function getAppDecision(){
var myCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
var i = myCollection.length;
console.log("  myCollection.length : " + i);
while(i--) {
    if (myCollection[i].innerText.search(/opened accounts/i) > -1) {
        console.log("==> spot 1 - open accounts");
        return;
    }
    if (myCollection[i].innerText.search(/being reviewed/i) > -1) {
        console.log("==> spot 2 - being reviewed");
        return;
    }
    if (myCollection[i].innerText.search(/verify your funding account/i) > -1) {
        console.log("==> spot 3 - verify");
        return;
    }
}
};
</script>
<div class="main">
<span id="firstSpan">
    <p> testing Being Reviewed</p>
    <p> testing Opened Accounts</p>
    <p> testing have Verify YOUR Funding account</p>
 </span>
</div>
<script>
getAppDecision();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the while loop to run over all your collection's items? Also, do you want other if conditions to be checked after the first or second gives true?

Comment: what do you mean of  first occurrence?

Comment: I want the loop to end once it finds the topmost match. In my example, it would be "testing Being Reviewed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myCollection` will not get the values you are looking for. You might want to change your code to have this:

```
var myCollection = [];
document.querySelectorAll('#firstSpan p')
   .forEach((elem) => myCollection.push(elem.innerText));
```

Than, you can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The **find()** method returns the **value** of **the first element** in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

It will stop on the first element that satisfies the condition.

You can do this:

```
var result = myCollection.find((item) => {
   return (item.search(/opened accounts/i) > -1)
          || (item.search(/being reviewed/i) > -1)
          || (item.search(/verify your funding account/i) > -1);
});
```

After that, `result` should have the value `testing Being Reviewed`, based on your example.

Comment: Just FYI...I made up the markup example. I have no control over the actual markup. The only thing I do know is that the text will be in the "main" div but after that, the structure within the main div may change. I just want to see which phrase occurs 1st as related to the position (top/bottom) of the webpage.

Comment: @MichaelJohns, that's cool. I guess my assumption for suggesting the `.find()` code is that `myCollection` would have all the innerText values of your `p` elements.